# Can't invoke GreenDroid PagedView OnClickListener

Tags: android

Finally I use setOnClickListener() on convertView in the adapter applied to the PagedView..

I works, but i don't think it's a good solution.

=================================================divider========2012.03.02=========

this is my first time asking question here, hope that someone nice could help me.

I'm using GreenDroid PagedView, but I want to click on the pagedView,and it simply not response.

I've tried to log in onClickListener method. But I just can't get that log.

The reason is that when i click on the screen ,seems that it don't invoke onClick method.

Anyone would help me?

Follow GreenDroid on GitHub Here.
https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

You can download and just run it ,no need to modify anything if you use Eclipse IDE.

CDCatalog-PagedViewActivity 
I just want to click on PagedView.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this very same problem. I have a viewflipper in the paged_view_item instead of just a textview. I am implementing an onClickListener in the getView method of the extended PagedAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.paged_view_item, parent, false);
            }
            ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView;

            viewFlipper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //ViewFlipper vf = 
                    ((ViewFlipper) view).setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom));
                    ((ViewFlipper)view).showNext();

                }

            });

            ((TextView)viewFlipper.findViewById(R.id.frontText)).setText(Integer.toString(position));
            return convertView;
        }
```

The only problem is that it flips all the viewflips in either the odd set of pages or even set of pages. It's really weird. Let me know how this works for you.